# Is it possible to redirect a logging output of the iptables' LOG chain into a separate log file?

Tags: logs, iptables

I don't want to mix `iptables`'s log output with other system logs. How could I specify a dedicated log file for `iptables` LOG chains output?

Comment: The same question got re-asked [here specifically for `rsyslog`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16053/1925).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you do this will depend on which log daemon you use, `syslog` or `syslog-ng`.

With *syslog*, you can do this by tweaking a specific log level to only contain `iptables` messages.

In `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
kern.warning     /var/log/iptables
```

The set `iptables` to use that log level:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4
```

With `syslog-ng` you should be able to get a little fancier. Instead of hacking a log level you can filter for content and send that content to a specific log file.

In `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`:

```
destination d_iptables { file("/var/log/iptables"); };
filter f_iptables { match("IN=[A-Za-z0-9\.]* OUT=[A-Za-z0-9\.]*" value("MESSAGE")); };
log { source(s_sys); filter(f_iptables); destination(d_iptables); }
```

Comment: I don't have neither '/etc/syslog/' nor '/etc/syslog-ng/' directories on my Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid system. But obviously there is some logging package. In case of 'syslog', as I understand, all messages for 'kern' facility at level 'warning' and above will go to the specified log file, so I can probably end up with mixed-output file also?

Comment: Looks like I have 'rsyslog' installed.

Comment: @mbaitoff: Yes, the level 4 warning was picked because it's not used very often, but yes you COULD end up with a mixup. I'm sorry I don't know `rsyslog`, but I'm sure there is a similar way to route messages to different log files based on the originating process or filtering.

Comment: Yes, looks like there is a way to use facility and level specification together with template message filtering and `--log-prefix` ability to forward matching messages to certain log file. I'd probably open another question regarding the `rsyslog`-way implementation of such a forwarding (as the manpage is pretty cryptic about it). Thanks for help with `syslog` and `syslog-ng` cases.

Comment: What I do on my system is use a unique string in each LOG message that is not likely to appear in other messages (":%FW%:" is what I use currently).  You can then tell `syslog` or `syslog-ng` to filter any incoming message containing that to its own file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
:msg,contains,"IPTABLES:" /var/log/iptables
& stop
```

It should be added before any other rules, for example:

```
:msg,contains,"IPTABLES:" /var/log/iptables
& stop

auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
cron.*              /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
...
```

You just change the `IPTABLES:` to whatever you've set in the LOG target. If you wont use `& stop`, the message will be logged in both files, the standard `/var/log/syslog` file and in the `/var/log/iptables` .

It's a better solution than redirecting all kern.warning messages because in that case you can redirect some other information, not just the one you'd like.