# How to redirect kernel messages having the unique id substring into separate log file (using `rsyslog`)?

Tags: logs, iptables, rsyslog

I am using `iptables`'s logging feature to debug my network activity. I use certain prefix with `--log-prefix` parameter to uniquely identify messages in kernel log belonging to `iptables` output, for example `::IPT::LOG::`.

How can I configure `rsyslog` to redirect messages tagged that way into a separate log file? Man page for `rsyslog` looks too cryptic to me.

Comment: For answers to the same problem for `syslog` and `syslog-ng`, see [this thread about the same problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16038/1925).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition on selector-based filtering, rsyslogd can filter on patterns found in log message properties. To accomplish what you are trying to do, you can create a property-based filter to match the string you are using in your iptables rules. If you were to use `--log-prefix "unique_prefix: "` in your iptables rule, you would need to add this to rsyslog.conf:

```
:msg,startswith,"unique_prefix" /var/log/iptables
```

This rule will test log messages for your prefix and send them to /var/log/iptables (in addition to wherever else rsyslog is configured to send them). If you need to have the messages appear in /var/log/iptables but not elsewhere, place the new rule above others, and follow it with a line containing `& ~`. Complete example:

```
:msg,startswith,"unique_prefix" /var/log/iptables
& ~
#
# The rest of my rules appear below
# ...
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

Rsyslog rules can have multiple actions. Subsequent actions are defined on new lines beginning with an ampersand (`&`). In the example above, the first rule has two actions: send output to /var/log/iptables, and then discard message (`~`). See [rsyslog docs on actions](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html) and [filters](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) for more information on the rules in this answer

Edited to use `startswith` rather than `contains` for performance considerations. Since the iptables `--log-prefix` is indeed a prefix, and thus will be at the start of the message.

Comment: So in this case output will go to the both log files? How can I also indeed redirect the messages, so they don't appear in syslog, but in iptables' log only?

Comment: Added more complete example and information about rule actions

Comment: On my Debian (7 or 8) systems, the msg doesn't start with the log prefix. So I needed this regex instead : `:msg, regex, "^\[ *[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\] MyPrefix"` to match `Jan 23 18:11:35 myhost kernel: [607552.301334] MyPrefix IN=...`

Answer (score 1):

My experience, given the nature of how the `rsyslog.conf` file is parsed, the additional configuration lines in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` must be before all other configuration lines.  If added to the end of the file, the ip-tables logging will still be appended to `/var/log/messages` and also re-directed to the `/var/log/iptables.log` file.

Comment: Well that was useful! I was wondering why I still have 'iptables' rubbish in system log in addition to dedicated log.